# Adding marker to my gmaps4rails by javascript

Tags: gmaps4rails

I am having some problems using the gem gmaps4rails. I am using a mix of javascript and gmaps4rails. Here is a sample of my code:

```
       function handle_locations(position) {

        alert("Length = " + Gmaps.map.markers.length);
        var yourStartLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: yourStartLatLng});
        alert("Ola 2");

        if(document.getElementById("map") != null)
          alert("diff");

        Gmaps.map.markers[0] = marker;

        alert("Ola 333");
        //var map = $document.filter('#map');
        //var map = document.getElementById("map");
        //Gmaps.map.add_marker(marker);  
    }

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_locations);
```

The handle_locations function works fine and i can get my location. The problem is to add a marker to the map created using gmaps. how can i add my geolocaton marker to the map in this function?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and this worked for me.

```
lat = position.coords.latitude;
lng = position.coords.longitude;

Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
   Gmaps.map.createMarker({
      Lat: lat,
      Lng: lng, 
      rich_marker: null, 
      marker_picture: ""
   });
}
```

Make sure you use position.coords.latitude/longitude only after the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {` 
request has succeeded (propably you are doing so), because getting the location from user is asyncronous and will take some time.

You can check that you have the right lat and lng with

```
alert(lat+" "+lng);
```